# jnlp suddenly broken with java web start

Tags: java, macos, jnlp, java-web-start

I am seeing a problem with Web App Start running the same old jnlp.

I have been running on Mac, Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0, forever. All of a sudden, I am not able to run the app from web start.

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-10M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
```

from the console, I run

```
javaws ./my.jnlp 
Java Web Start splash screen process exiting .....
    Bad installation. No JRE found in configuration file
```

the jnlp file contains:

```xml
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
<j2se version="1.4+" initial-heap-size="128m" max-heap-size="256m" />
```

Not sure what is going on? Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should your problem reappear, or should somebody else run into the same problem... Oracle's Mac Java FAQ states: "[Apple disables the Java plug-in and Webstart applications when the Java update is done using Software Update](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml#software%20upgrade)."  You can download Java 7 for the Mac from Oracle and use it for Webstart.  See https://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp

Apple has been intermittently issuing software updates which disable Java applets and Webstart for awhile, so the problem may indeed resurface later.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the software update for Java on my Mac and the problem disappeared.
It came as a mystery, only fair for it to go away in mystery also.